# How to get the equation to look in a required format?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I am still new in LaTeX - beginner. How can I have the equation to look like this (the example is shown in ms word):

```
Lexical level:      f o x + plural (‘+’ is a morpheme boundary)

Surface level:      f o x e s

Two-level rule:     e:+ ↔ x:x _ 0:s
```

[image: image of example]

The 'f' at lexical level must be align with the 'f' at the surface level. Do I have to put it in a table so that each of the characters can be aligned?

Comment: Could you please add an image? (I know, you cannot directly add images yet, but just upload it to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the link -- the image can then be integrated once you have 10 rep)

Comment: here you goes: http://imgur.com/pAzfS?full

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be a tabbing environment:

```
 \begin{tabbing}
 Lexical level:\qquad \=f~\=o~\=x + plural (`+' is a morpheme boundary)\\
 Surface level:       \>f \>o \>x~e~s\\
 \\
 Two-level rule:     \>e:\textsuperscript{+} $\leftrightarrow$ x:x \_ 0:s
 \end{tabbing}
```

\= sets a tab stop on the first line. \> moves to it on the next line and subsequent ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align the 'f' on each level, a table is probably easiest:

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Lexical level:    &    f o x + plural   \\
Surface level:    &    f o x e s        \\
\end{tabular}
```

The basic table environment is `tabular`. The `rl` means the table has two columns, the first right-justified and the second left-justified. Then just put in your entries row-by-row, using `&` to skip to the next column and `\\` to skip to the next row. This is probably enough for your current purposes, but when you end up wanting to make a proper table you should check out [the LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

As for the other part of your question, I'm afraid I don't have enough linguistics training to know what "e:+ ↔ x:x _ 0:s" should look like. It would be great if you could point us to an example of what you'd like to get. That being said, you can get ↔ with `$\leftrightarrow$`; an underscore with `\_` or a longer underlined space with `\rule{1cm}` or `\underline{\hspace{1cm}}`; and ∅ (if you're looking for that instead of 0) with `\emptyset` or `\varnothing`.

Comment: I wondering if using an inline verbatim from the listings package would help to vertically align the characters in `f o x e s`

Comment: @Will It can be achieved using a  monospace font

Comment: @Will, @Yiannis: a monospace font would certainly work to vertically align the characters in `f o x e s`, using `\verb` or otherwise. This might not be great for aligning the `f`s in the first place, though. It works in this case --- fortunately, "Lexical" and "Surface" have the same number of letters! --- but in general you'd have to add verbatim spaces (or worse) to get the spacing exactly right.

Comment: guys, i just tried using tabbing environment and it works!